# Unable to mark a Contract as inProgress() with Spring Cloud Contract

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

We need to temporary mark one of our Contracts as [inProgress()](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-dsl-in-progress).

Here's how I try to do it:

```
Contract.make {
  inProgress()
  description "should do a thing"

  request {
    //request definition here
  }

  response {
    //response definition here
  }
```

Without the "inProgress()" line everything builds and runs ok, but with it I get this error when trying to run contractTest gradle task.

```
Spring Cloud Contract Verifier Plugin exception: Process 'command 'C:\path\to\jdk\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Frustratingly enough, stacktrace or logs don't provide any details of what the actual error is. Any ideas on how to debug this are much appreciated.

spring-cloud-contract-dependencies version is 4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I incorrectly assumed that failOnInProgress gradle plugin property would be set to false by default. Since the docs said "You can set the value of the failOnInProgress [...] to ensure that your build will break..." it seemed to me that not setting it would guarantee a pass.

Setting the property to false explicitly fixed the issue.